# Delphi Change modal form Caption

Tags: delphi, forms, modal-dialog

How Can I change a modal forms caption while it is showing, from within the modal form.

Thanks

Colin

Comment: You set it the same way as from anywhere else with the Caption property

Comment: I thought that however it does not seem to work ona modal form?

Comment: it works fine on a modal form. The problem must be in your code.

Comment: Sorry my mistake  A bit of Ropey code by me thanks colin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way as you change the caption of any form.

There are a thousand ways, depending on *when* you want to change the caption. One way is this: Drop a `TButton` on your modal form, and write

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := 'New caption';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure MyMainForm.ShowForm(ACaption: String);
var
  dlgForm: TForm;
begin
  dlgForm:= TForm.Create(Nil);
  try
    dlgForm.Caption:= ACaption;
    dlgForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(dlgForm);
  end;
end;
```